# Automating heap dumps from an Android device or emulator

Tags: android, bash, shell

I've automated the process of extracting and converting a heap dump from an Android device/emulator.

I'd appreciate any feedback and improvements regarding style, bad practices, non-idiomatic code, performance or other issues you may find.

Also, `dump_heap()` function tries to wait for a daemon to complete and I'm wondering if there are better ways to handle the situation.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Extracts a heap dump from a device/emulator. 
# Assumes the appropriate tools (adb, hprof-conv) are included in the path.

SERIAL=""
PACKAGE=""
FILE=""

usage() {
    echo "Usage: -s <serialNumber> -p <package> -f <file>"
    exit 1
}

err() {
    local msg="$1"
    echo "$msg" >&2
    exit 1
}

create_file() {
    local file=$1
    local dir=$(dirname "$file")

    mkdir -p -- "$dir" && touch -- "$file"  

    if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then 
        err "File $file could not be created."
    fi
}

file_size_on_device() {
    local adbcmd="adb -s $SERIAL"
    local file="$1"
    local adbinfo="$adbcmd shell ls -l $file"

    $adbinfo | awk '{print $4}'
}

dump_heap() {
    local adbcmd="adb -s $SERIAL"
    local pid="$1"
    local file="$2"
    local dir=$(dirname "$file")

    # Remove any existing tmp files we created. Ideally, there should be none.
    local exists=$($adbcmd shell ls "$dir" | grep "$file")
    if [ -n "$exists" ]; then
        $adbcmd shell rm "$file"
    fi

    echo -n "Dumping heap "

    # Dump the heap to a tmp file on a device/emulator
    $adbcmd shell am dumpheap "$pid" "$file"

    # Beacuse the previous cmd runs as a daemon, we have to wait for it to 
    # finish. The following checks the tmp file size continuously, stopping
    # when it's not changing anymore.  
    sleepinterval=0.5

    s0=-1
    sleep $sleepinterval
    s1=$(file_size_on_device "$file")

    while ((s1 > s0))
    do 
        echo -n "."
        sleep $sleepinterval
        let s0=$s1
        let s1=$(file_size_on_device "$file")
    done

    echo " Done"
}

extract_from_device() { 
    local adbcmd="adb -s $SERIAL"

    local pid=$($adbcmd shell ps | grep $PACKAGE | awk '{print $2}')
    if [ -z "${pid}" ]; then
        err "PID for $PACKAGE not found. Is your app installed and running?"
    fi

    # Dump heap to tmp file on a device
    local file="/sdcard/hprof___tmp"
    dump_heap "$pid" "$file"

    # Extract
    local tmp="$FILE-nonconv"   
    create_file $tmp
    $adbcmd pull -p $file $tmp

    # Convert
    if [ -s "$tmp" ]; then
        create_file $FILE   
        hprof-conv $tmp $FILE
    else
        echo "No data to convert."
    fi

    # Finish
    $adbcmd shell rm "$file"
    rm -- $tmp

    echo "Done, converted heap extracted to $FILE"
}

while getopts ":s::p::f:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        s) SERIAL="$OPTARG";;
        p) PACKAGE="$OPTARG";;
        f) FILE="$OPTARG";;
        *) usage;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "${SERIAL}" ] || [ -z "${PACKAGE}" ] || [ -z "${FILE}" ]; then
    usage
else 
    version=$(adb -s "$SERIAL" shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk | tr -d '\r')
    if [ "$version" -gt "10" ]; then
        extract_from_device
    else 
        err "The target device/emulator must be API 11 or above."
    fi
fi
```

The above is part of [Dumpey](https://github.com/tslamic/Dumpey), which helps you

- run the monkey on multiple devices or emulators and
- make converted memory heap dumps before and after it

Comment: I believe that `getopts` string should just be `:s:p:f:` for silent mode and a required argument for each of the `s`, `p` and `f` flags.

Comment: Storing commands in strings is generally not a good idea (as with `adbcmd` and `adbinfo`). Anything complicated breaks. If you *must* store it using an array is much better but it doesn't look like you need to here.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll fix what you’ve pointed out. If there’s anything else fishy, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code passes on http://www.shellcheck.net/# with flying colors, congrats!

#### Simplify variable initializations

Here you can drop all the `""`, it will be the same thing but easier to write:

> ```
> SERIAL=""
> PACKAGE=""
> FILE=""
> ```

That is, like this:

```
SERIAL=
PACKAGE=
FILE=
```

#### Check if a regular file exists with `-f` instead of `-e`

I admire your paranoia, with all the `--`:

> ```
> mkdir -p -- "$dir" && touch -- "$file"  
>
> if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then 
>     err "File $file could not be created."
> fi
> ```

But I would also recommend to use `-f` instead of `-e`,
as you are really expecting a regular file,
and `-e` is not necessary a regular file, can be a directory too.

#### Avoid putting commands into variables, especially when used only once

About this code:

> ```
> local adbinfo="$adbcmd shell ls -l $file"
>
> $adbinfo | awk '{print $4}'
> ```

When the command in `$adbinfo` becomes anything non-trivial,
running the command with `$adbinfo | ...` may not work as expected.
As long as you keep that in mind, this is fine.
However, since you only use this command once in the `file_size_on_device` function,
I recommend to not use `$adbinfo` at all, but the command directly:

```
$adbcmd shell ls -l $file | awk '{print $4}'
```

Even so, just keep in mind that the same dangers exist for `$adbcmd` as for `$adbinfo` earlier. But at least we removed one layer of danger (`$adbinfo`),
so that's a good thing.

#### Simplify `ls | grep`, use just `ls` when it's good enough

In `dump_heap`, I'm wondering if this actually works as expected:

> ```
> # Remove any existing tmp files we created. Ideally, there should be none.
> local exists=$($adbcmd shell ls "$dir" | grep "$file")
> if [ -n "$exists" ]; then
>     $adbcmd shell rm "$file"
> fi
> ```

In particular, it seems to me the `rm` command should be like this:

```
$adbcmd shell rm "$dir/$file"
```

Because `ls "$dir" | grep "$file"` suggests that `$file` is just a filename,
not an absolute path, inside the directory `$dir`.

Also, the call to `grep` seems unnecessary, a single `ls` command should do:

```
local exists=$($adbcmd shell ls "$dir/$file")
```

#### Simplifying conditions

Still in `dump_heap`,
when checking if `$exists` is non-empty, instead of `-n "$exists"`,
you can just drop the `-n`, simply `[ "$exists" ]` is the same thing.

Lastly, I'm wondering if the whole thing can be simplified to:

```
# Remove any existing tmp files we created. Ideally, there should be none.
$adbcmd shell ls "$dir/$file" &>/dev/null && $adbcmd shell rm "$dir/$file"
```

#### Prefer `printf` over `echo` for non-trivial printing

The various flags of `echo` are unreliable.
Depending on your system, they might work as expected or not.
Rather than using any of the flags of `echo`, I prefer `printf`.
So instead of:

> ```
> echo -n "Dumping heap "
> ```

I recommend:

```
printf "Dumping heap "
```

However, I prefer `echo` when printing trivial text, 
without using any flags,
and when I want a terminating newline.

#### Prefer fewer processes

In this pipeline there are 3 processes: `adb`, `grep` and `awk`

```
local pid=$($adbcmd shell ps | grep $PACKAGE | awk '{print $2}')
```

Especially in cases when an `awk` follows a `grep`,
one begs the question if the task of `grep` can be included in the `awk` command.
And in this case yes:

```
local pid=$($adbcmd shell ps | awk -v pkg=$PACKAGE '$0 ~ pkg {print $2}')
```

However, a little laziness is not against the spirit of good shell scripting.
Your version with `grep` is shorter and simpler,
and on most days I would go with it too.
So this remark is just for the record, and for the meticulous.

#### Simplify condition

Instead of this:

> ```
> if [ -z "${SERIAL}" ] || [ -z "${PACKAGE}" ] || [ -z "${FILE}" ]; then
> ```

I suggest to simplify like this:

```
if ! [ "$SERIAL" -a "$PACKAGE" -a "$FILE" ]; then
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for a great review janos, this is exactly what I was looking for!